# Android/Java Instantiating a class multiple times

Tags: java, android, class, instantiation

I'm using [SugarORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html) to help with SQLite in an Android app. I am using the code below to add new rows to a table:

```
MyTable d = new MyTable("Row1_Title",valueRow1,stockRow1);
d.save();
MyTable d2 = new MyTable("Row2_Title",valueRow2,stockRow2);
d2.save();
MyTable d3 = new MyTable("Row3_Title",valueRow3,stockRow3);
d3.save();
MyTable d4 = new MyTable("Row4_Title",valueRow4,stockRow4);
d4.save();
MyTable d5 = new MyTable("Row5_Title",valueRow5,stockRow5);
d5.save();
MyTable d6 = new MyTable("Row6_Title",valueRow6,stockRow6);
d6.save();
MyTable d7 = new MyTable("Row7_Title",valueRow7,stockRow7);
d7.save();
```

**MyTable Constructor**

```
public MyTable(String title, int value, int stock){
        this.title = title;
        this.value = value;
        this.stock = stock;
    }
```

This all works fine, but is this the right way to instantiate a class multiple times? It seems like I should be able to combine the instantiating in some way?

Thanks

Comment: You could use d = new MyTable() back instead of having all these instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. If you want to initialize different variables with different parameters in the constructor this is the way to do it.

There are other things you can do, but that would involve changing other parts of your code and they aren't any more simple (ex: making an array of `MyTable` objects).

Answer (score 0):

You could also make a 2D Object array for the values, which would maybe be a bit more clear, but as @cbender already pointed out, it would change your code somewhere else.